# retrieving data from database using id and displaying it in view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listview, asp.net-mvc-4, ado.net-entity-data-model

My problem is in view...Please give me new view which suits my database and action.

My details table:

[image: Details table]

Passing request id using html action link:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.Request_ID, "Details",new { requestid = item.Request_ID },null )
```

clicking on the link we should get details corresponding to the link from database.

Action method:

```
public ActionResult Details(string requestid)
    {
        var entities = new EmployDBEntities1();
       var detailsModel = entities.Details.Single(e => e.Id == requestid);
       return View(detailsModel);
        //return View(entities.Details.ToList());
    }
```

Hope my problem is returning view and designing view. My requirement is I want details for particular id and should display them in the below designed view. I am able to check the ids in var details model and then I have to read remaining fields from databse and disply the fields in my view.I am notable to do it. Please help me.

### View:

```
model IEnumerable<Approvals.Models.Detail>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
//Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Header {
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "PendingRequests", "Account", null, new { data_icon = "arrow-l", data_rel = "back" })
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff") 


}

<head>
 <link href="~/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<div data-role="collapsible"  data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Employee Details</h3>
    <table class="td3">
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.EmpID)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Short ID</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(item.ShortID)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Grade</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.Grade)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Vertical</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.Vertical)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Vertical Head</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.VerticalHead)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>L1 Manager</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.L1_Manager)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>L2 Manager</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.L2_Mnager)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>CostCentre</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(item.CostCentre)</td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: @AmitAgrawal... when i am cliking request id it is giving "error loading page"... this is because I gave return view(detailsmodel) and in view I am reading data from details table...But I don't know how to define my view to read details of particular request id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    model Approvals.Models.Detail

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Details";
//Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section Header {
@Html.ActionLink("Back", "PendingRequests", "Account", null, new { data_icon = "arrow-l", data_rel = "back" })
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff") 


}

<head>
 <link href="~/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<div data-role="collapsible"  data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">
    <h3>Employee Details</h3>
    <table class="td3">
        <tr>
            <td>Employee ID</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.EmpID)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Short ID</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.Encode(Model.ShortID)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Grade</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.Grade)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Vertical</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.Vertical)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Vertical Head</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.VerticalHead)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>L1 Manager</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.L1_Manager)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>L2 Manager</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.L2_Mnager)</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>CostCentre</td>
            <td>@Html.Encode(Model.CostCentre)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of var type for detailsModel object give type what is bound to view i.e. IEnumerable of Approvals.Models.Detail in "Details" action.
2. your view name should match action name if not supplied in return View(). else return View("xxx", detailsModel ) in "Details" action.

Comment: var entities = new EmployDBEntities1(); IEnumerable<Approvals.Models.Detail> detailsModel = entities.Details.Single(e => e.Id == requestid);                        return View("Details",detailsModel);  ..by doing this i am getting error near entities.Details.Single()

Comment: remove IEnumerable from detailsModel type because .Single() return single object not IEnumerable. also remove this from view and remove foreach on Model.

Comment: Action method: var entities = new EmployDBEntities1();
        Approvals.Models.Detail detailsModel = entities.Details.Single(e => e.Id == requestid);
           return View("Details",detailsModel);                    my view : @model Approvals.Models.Detail  removed IEnumerable... again I am getting error loading page...

Comment: Just give tell me how to write my view I am using ado.net and .edmx diagram to retrieve data from database. Give me new view so that it will work.